# Formula to dynamically create column of values, excluding some by criteria

Tags: excel

Say I have a column with these values on Sheet1:

```
IDs
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Then a column with these values on Sheet2:

```
Used IDs
2
3
6
```

Is there a clever way I can write a formula on Sheet3 that shows only the IDs that are visible on Sheet1 but NOT on sheet2?  Like this:

```
Unused IDs
1
4
5
```

I need something that would update dynamically as move values are added to the 
Used IDs' column on Sheet2.  I can make something work that simply omits the used IDs (retaining their rows as NULL), like this:

```
Unused IDs
1


4
5
```

However, I need something without the blank rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in A1 in Sheet3 and copy down till blanks:

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6)/(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6,Sheet2!A:A,0)))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: That's perfect and useful to learn from.  This is really interesting for my more complicated real life application.